# Activate "ibidtracker" and "idemtracker" in footnotes only (authortitle-dw style)

Tags: footnotes, shorthands, ibidem

I am using the bibliography style `authortitle-dw` and am trying to figure out whether it is possible to activate "ibidtracker" and "idemtracker" in footnotes only. I am using shorthands for citations of some sources in my main text (bracketed using the \parencite command) and I do not want "ibid"/"ebd." to apply to the shorthands cited in brackets in the main text.

What I would like to get is this:

Text Text Text (Shorthand 1, p. X) Text Text Text(1) Text Text Text (Shorthand 1, p. X) Text Text Text(2).

––––––––––––

(1) Source 1.

(2) Ebd.

Can anyone help me in achieving this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{report}
\usepackage[left=5cm, top=2cm, right=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\raggedbottom
\usepackage{mystyle}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\begin{document}

Text Text Text \parencite[1]{WRP} Text Text Text\footnote{\cite[1]{Wellmer}} Text Text Text \parencite[1]{WRP} Text Text Text\footnote{\cite[1]{Wellmer}}.

\end{document}
```

Here's what's in my `mystyle.sty` file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}[2020/05/21 FUX's custom LaTeX style]

%Custom preamble

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

%Das Nachfolgende ist der Zitationsstil mit allen seinen Optionen:

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authortitle-dw,
    useprefix=true,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    nopublisher=true,
    nolocation=false,
    citedas=true,
    citeauthorname=firstfull,
    firstfull=true,
    acronyms=true,
    idembib=true,
    idembibformat=dash,
    edbyidem=true,
    editorstring=parens,
    ibidtracker=context,
    editionstring=true,
    series=beforeedition,
    seriesformat=standard,
    shorthandinbib=false,
    terselos=true,
    pageref=false,
    loccittracker=true,
    idemtracker=true,
    shorthandwidth=108pt,
    citepages=separate,
    ]{biblatex}
    
    
    \renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifbool{cbx:inreffull}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:inreffull}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:firstfull}
      {\ifciteseen
        {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}
        {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:firstfull}}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}}}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
```

And here's what's in my `literatur.bib` file:

```
@book{Wellmer,
  author      = {Wellmer, Albrecht}, 
  title       = {Sprachphilosophie. Eine Vorlesung},
  shorttitle  = {Sprachphilosophie},
  editor      = {Hoffmann, Thomas and Rebentisch, Juliane and Sonderegger, Ruth},
  publisher   = {Suhrkamp},
  year        = 2004,
  address     = {Frankfurt/M.},
  }
  
  
@book{WRP,
  author      = {Kripke, Saul A.}, 
  title       = {Wittgenstein über Regeln und Privatsprache. Eine elementare Darstellung},
  options     = {acronym=true},
  shorthand   = {WRP},
  publisher   = {Suhrkamp},
  year        = 1987,
  address     = {Frankfurt/M.},
  }
```